# Using transparent images and repeat

Tags: css, user-interface

I have a tab and would like a custom image to underline part of the text in the tab.  I have 3 images, left image transparent for 14px and then 1 pixel wide of colour, a right image that is the reverse of this, and a 1 px wide image that repeats.

I have found that the middle repeat image is visible in the transparent part of the left and right images (essentially making the transparent part redundant).  Is this something with a work around?  I have not found anything on the net, although it is a very generic search too.

I'm using the following css for the images:

```
background-image:url(15pxRight.png), url(15pxLeft.png), url(1px.png); 
background-position: bottom right, bottom left, bottom center;
background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
```

I do not want to use a colour as the background tab changes colour if it is selected.  Is this possible to fix?

Comment: can you share your HTML? And why can't you just use CSS for this, and set classes for the specific color when it changes? Have you entertained the idea of setting :active for the class of the tab that is changed so it can use a specific background color when clicked/active?

Comment: Hi Michael - this is all part of a much larger framework which is why I had not included the html - there is a massive amount of code.  Was just trying to snip out the part I thought was relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking why the 3rd 1px image is appearing beneath the transparent sections of the other two background images, then the answer is because it's set to `repeat-x`.

The 3 background images will be "layered" on top of one another. Not set side by side, which is what I suspect you think they will do.

So no matter how small the 3rd image is, if it's set to repeat-x, then it will cover the entire width of its container. And even though it will be "behind" the other two images, it will show through where the "higher" layer images have transparent pixels that overlap the lower images.

Comment: Thanks - you are correct.  That is what I was hoping they would be side by side, and not layered.  I have a work around by not having the transparent part of the image.  Any tips on how people usually get this to work?

Comment: what you're doing is relatively odd. But if you needed to do exactly what you're doing, then you would use another div centered inside the current div, but at a reduced width, and have your 1px image repeat inside the inner div.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, it is, however I am trying to make something look a bit nicer in a restricted environment.  Appreciate your assistance here and getting me on the right path.